# Issue with my ASP.NET Visual Basic Web Forms App

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, webforms

I am encountering an issue whilst debugging my ***ASP.NET Web Forms Web Application*** I have been encountering these issues since I have laid out the code to allow for an admin section on the app.

**Error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'..

**Stack Trace**

> [InvalidOperationException: 'respond' is not a valid script name.  The name must end in '.js'.]
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetDebugName(String releaseName) +139
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.ShouldUseDebugScript(String releaseName, Assembly assembly, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, Assembly currentAjaxAssembly) +31
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.DetermineResourceNameAndAssembly(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean isDebuggingEnabled, String& resourceName, Assembly& assembly) +97
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName(ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +104
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlInternal(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip, Boolean useCdnPath) +603
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean zip) +185
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterUniqueScripts(List`1 uniqueScripts) +204
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +465
>      System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +124
>      System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +9753946
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5054

**What have I tried so far?**

On my *master page* I tried adding '.js' at the end of 'respond' making it 'respond.js'. (see below)

```
    <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="AccessGP.SiteMaster" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="AccessGP" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" visible="false" href="~/Admin/AdminPage.aspx">Admin Area</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I debug it breaks with another error, as follows:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'jquery.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

**Does anyone have any suggestions? As a newbie, I hope my question is worded clearly etc. Thanks in advance.**

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!--Elmah section-->
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!--Dot Net Auth-->
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <!--Connection to database-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccessGP-20170327062552.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccessGP-20170327062552;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AccessGP" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccessGP-20170402220741;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccessGP-20170402220741.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <!--Custom Errors-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config" />
    </customErrors>
    <!--Custom Errors END-->
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--Profile Provider-->
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <!--Profile Provider END-->
    <!--Membership Provider-->
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!--Membership Provider END-->
    <!--Role Manager-->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--Session State-->
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <!--<add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider,               , Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />-->
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <!--Http Modules-->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah>
  <!--Elmah location-->
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
      <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
      <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
    <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. --><!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>--></settings>
  </system.net>
  <!--I am at this stage here!!!-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  <!-- This prevents the Windows Event Log from frequently logging that HMAC1 is being used (when the other party needs it). --><legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" /><!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 3, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 and 2 references relink
             to MVC 3 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it.
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
         --></runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
<dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
                    <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
        <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
        <reporting enabled="true" />
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. --><!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ --><openid>
        <relyingParty>
                <security requireSsl="false">
                    <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
                    <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
                </security>
                <behaviors>
                    <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
                </behaviors>
            </relyingParty></openid></dotNetOpenAuth><uri>
        <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
        <idn enabled="All" />
        <iriParsing enabled="true" />
    </uri></configuration>
```

Comment: We do not need your entire web.config. Just the relevant bits, if any. If you aren't sure what to include in your question, please review [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @mason for pointing this out. Are you able to have a look at this?

Comment: The error seems straightforward enough to me. It's expecting `jquery.js` to be registered and it's not seeing it. So you need to check your registrations and *show* them in your question.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. I had a line missing from Global.asax.vb file

`RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`

Thanks for your help nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue. The following line was missing from *Global.asax.vb*

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
```